# how to monitor shared/network printers through windows service?

Tags: windows-services

I can retrieve all printers(including network printers) using windows application and also able to monitor them. I am using Print Spooler API's for them. But, if I run same code in windows service, I am not able to retrieve the network printers. Because network/shared printer will only be visible if you log in as specific Windows account and service is always login as 'SYSTEM' account.

Can we monitor these network printers using service?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to set the Windows Service's login as a user that has permission to manage the print queues on the server or workstations you're trying to monitor.

Select the "This Account" option on the "Log On" tab in the Services Control Panel and specify an account that has the necessary permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... But I have already tried that way. It won't work in my case. I have tried to 'login' with all available users but it can not monitor network printer in any case.

Comment: You'll need to attach to your running service using the Visual Studio Debugger and see what and where the actual error is.

Comment: I didn't get any error in that case. Just EnumPrinters() API is not giving any network printer in printer list.

Comment: If you post your code I can take a look at it. Are you trying to access a remote print server?